# Powershell to find specific pattern

Tags: regex, powershell, jira

I am trying to extract only my JIRA issue numbers from a text file, eliminating duplicates. This is good in Shell script:

```
 cat /tmp/jira.txt | grep -oE '^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+' | sort -u
```

But I want to use Powershell and tried this

```
$Jira_Num=Get-Content /tmp/jira.txt |  Select-String -Pattern '^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+' > "$outputDir\numbers.txt"
```

But, this returns the entire line also not eliminating the duplicates.  I tried regex but I am new to powershell don't know how exactly to use it. Can someone help please.

Sample Jira.txt file

```
 PRJ-2303 Modified the artifactName
 PRJ-2303 Modified comment
 JIRA-1034 changed url to tag the prj projects
 JIRA-1000 for release 1.1
 JIRA-1000 Content modification
```

Expected output

```
 PRJ-2303
 JIRA-1034
 JIRA-1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work with something like this:

```psh
$Jira_Num = Get-Content /tmp/jira.txt | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_ -match '^([A-Z]+-[0-9]+)') {
        $Matches[1]
    }
} | Select-Object -Unique
```

`Get-Content` reads a file line by line, so we can pipe it to other cmdlets to process each line.

`ForEach-Object` runs a command block for each item in the pipeline. So here we're using the `-match` operator to perform a regex match against the line, with a capturing group. If the match succeeds, we send the matched group (the JIRA issue key) down the pipeline.

`Select-Object -Unique` will compare the objects and return only the unique ones.

Comment: @VRK now that you've posted the contents of your text file, are you trying to do something with git commits and updating JIRA issues? Atlassian has a [free plugin for BitBucket and GitHub](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-bitbucket-connector-plugin), but it doesn't work with GitLab. My company recently purchased a [GitLab plugin for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.allenta.jira.plugins.gitlab.gitlab-listener) and it's working well (I have no affiliation with them).

Comment: Thank you briantist! I am actually trying to get the fix versions of all the JIRA issues and do an audit to check if they match the current release's fix version number. I am using REST API to do that.

Answer (score 2):

`Select-String` can still work! The problem comes from the misconception of the return *object*. It returns a `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]` and it would appear it ToString() equivalent is the whole matching line. I don't know what version of PowerShell you have but this should do the trick.

```
$Jira_Num = Get-Content /tmp/jira.txt | 
    Select-String  -Pattern '^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+' | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value -Unique
```

Also you can get odd results when you are writing to an output stream and a variable at the same time. It is generally better to use [`Tee-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) in cases like that.

```
Select-String /tmp/jira.txt -Pattern '^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+' | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value -Unique | 
    Tee-Object -Variable Jira_Num | 
    Set-Content "$outputDir\numbers.txt"
```

Now the file `$outputDir\numbers.txt` and the variable `$Jira_Num` contain the unique list. The `$` not used with `Tee-Object` was done on purpose.

Comment: +1 for a solution using `Select-String`. I don't know why I just don't like that cmdlet; I basically never use it, and I realize this is entirely unjustified. :)